# Parse REST API set ACL to an object

Tags: rest, curl, parse-platform

I'm trying to set the ACL permissions for an object created through the Parse REST API. I want it to have only public read access. Only the server can create or modify the objects in the class. I read the parse REST documentation on how to set ACL permissions.

When I run the following:

```
$InputData = array('votes' => 1, 'ACL' => array('*' => array('read' => true, 'write' => false)), 'user' => array('__type' => 'Pointer', 'className' => '_User', 'objectId' => $objectId));

$rest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_PORT,443);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($InputData));
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array("X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
        "X-Parse-Master-Key: " . $restKey,
        "Content-Type: application/json"));
```

I get:

```
{"code":123,"error":"Invalid acl {\"*\":{\"read\":false,\"write\":false}}"} 1
```

What is wrong with my code, specifically the ACL part? Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it helps.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-H "X-Parse-Session-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-d "{\"name\":\"MyName\", \"ACL\": {\"ErKLiQfj8Q\" : { \"read\": true, \"write\": true }, \"*\" : {}}}" \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Tasks
```

**JSON obj**

```
{
  "name":"MyName",
  "ACL":
    {
        "ErKLiQfj8Q" : { "read": true, "write": true },
        "*" : {}
    }
}
```